# Android Jsoup.connect().get() takes very long time in android 4.4 versions

Tags: android, http, get, jsoup

When working with jsoup the get() method takes extremly long time when working with android 4.4 versions

a simple http read on android 4.1 takes about 5-10 sec anf on android 4.4 takes about 100 sec

any has an idea how to solve this ?

here a sample code:

```js
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II")
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36")
               .referrer("http://www.google.com")
               .get();
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that demonstrates this?

Comment: On target or on virtual machine?

Comment: on a target. tried few phones